# Error 404 for the url http://localhost:8081/jars/:jarid/run

Tags: apache-flink

I have jar file that already upload in flink cluster. I'm using flink 1.6.0

Here is the result after i uploaded the jar file

```
address "http://localhost:8081"
files   
  0 
    id        "1d6dc437-bd5f-4147-a37e-b1d40d425a99_NicoWordCount.jar"
    name      "NicoWordCount.jar"
    uploaded  1537174925000
    entry   
      0 
        name         "WordCount"
        description  null
```

When I run the following url

"http://localhost:8081/jars/1d6dc437-bd5f-4147-a37e-b1d40d425a99_NicoWordCount.jar/run" 
it returns: Failure: 404 Not Found

When I run

"http://localhost:8081/jars/1d6dc437-bd5f-4147-a37e-b1d40d425a99_NicoWordCount.jar/plan"

it returns a result.

When I run NicoWordCount.jar in flink dashboard, it also run well and gives the expected result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which HTTP method do you use?

Run should be executed with `POST`. For more info on flink's API check this [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/monitoring/rest_api.html#dispatcher).

Comment: when i tried using postman and method post it's working.
maybe my mistake in source.
thx David Wysakowicz